Fresh, slow, Ubuntu 24.04 installation - how to troubleshoot
A simple command like:
sudo apt remove --purge modemmanager brltty


took about 4 minutes.   (20-core i9 , 64GB RAM, M2.SSD)

At the same time, desktop is responsive, video plays fine, I open another terminal and may wait for 20 seconds to get dmesg output while uninstalling.
File browsing (changing directory in GUI browser, is slow too)
Ubuntu 23.10 worked fine, but I clean-installed after many years of upgrading.
How can I make it work "normally" / fine.

Look at the output of journalctl -r. Do you see any repeated error message?

Thank you, before troubleshooting I updated and rebooted again, (in a incorrect belief that journalctr output would restart/drop the old messages.)
After the reboot, the issue is gone. File browser is fast and all seems good. Maybe this was just the update that I needed, maybe the slowness will come back tomorrow.

Feel free to update the question and feel free to ping us

After 10hrs or so, the issue is back, in file browser, switching to "documents" takes about  4 secods, to "Downloads" about 5 seconds, every time.
I can't tell that those are syncronized to the issue, but I see :
May 10 09:51:14 loke tracker-miner-fs-3[32392]: (tracker-extract-3:32392): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 09:51:14.098: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
repeating now and then

Can you check whether swap usage is very high (open system monitor)? If so, disable the swapfile entry in fstab and reboot, and the issue should not come back.

no swap usage (says 0%) - 64GB of RAM.  Also, i now know that the issue "comes and goes" - right now it is not reproducible.
